# UIWindow addSubview position

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to add a button on the UIWindow on a specific position (bottom right corner). The button appears well on the view but is not in the right position. It always appears at the top left corner (x: 0, y: 0).

How can I do that?

My code:

```
@IBOutlet var myButton: ANLongTapButton!

// MARK: - View Lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let titleString = "Title\n"
    let hintString = "SubTitle"
    let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleString + hintString)
    let titleAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clearColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18)!]
    let hitAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clearColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)!]
    title.setAttributes(titleAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, titleString.characters.count))
    title.setAttributes(hitAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(titleString.characters.count, hintString.characters.count))

    myButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    myButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    myButton.setAttributedTitle(title, forState: .Normal)

    let win:UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!
    win.addSubview(myButton)
}
```

Note: I'm trying to add my button on the UIWindow because I need to have the button on the other view controllers as well.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/antrix1989/ANLongTapButton) button library.

---

**UPDATE**
I resolved my problem by adding constraints :

```
@IBOutlet var myButton: ANLongTapButton!

// MARK: - View Lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let titleString = "Title\n"
    let hintString = "SubTitle"
    let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleString + hintString)
    let titleAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clearColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18)!]
    let hitAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clearColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)!]
    title.setAttributes(titleAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, titleString.characters.count))
    title.setAttributes(hitAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(titleString.characters.count, hintString.characters.count))

    myButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    myButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    myButton.setAttributedTitle(title, forState: .Normal)

    let win:UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!
    win.addSubview(myButton)

    win.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: win, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: -10))
    win.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: win, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -10))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display subview (your button) on the right position you have to specify its constraints or set the frame. When you're adding some view's subview to another view, constraints and positions are not carried.

Comment: Thx for the reply, i'm also trying to add constraint to the window but it doesn't work. Do you know how i can do it ?

Comment: Great! Hope my answer was helpful for you :)